# UITableView cell insertion failure

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to make a UITableView that can have expandable header views. When you press a button inside of the header view, the following function gets executed:

```
func expandTheCell(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()

    if sender.isExpanded == false {

        postsArray.append("Hello")
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("Array Count: \(postsArray.count)")
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: sender.tag)], with: .fade)

    } else {
        print("test")
    }

    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

This are some table view functions:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
    return postsArray.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```

When I try to insert the rows, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 1

How come I can't insert the cells? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try removing `tableView.reloadData()` and then run the program

Comment: Removed that, still doesn't work

Comment: also comment `postsArray.append("Hello")` for now and simply insert a row, does it give the error too?

Comment: Yes, still give the error even after I remove that

Comment: can you show the code for `numberOfSections`  method?

Comment: Ok, added it in my edit

Comment: Have you tried this without begin/end updates block? if no please try and if yes then what was the result?

Comment: Deleted both of them, did not fix it

Comment: you have **3** sections. Do all of them have the same amount of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is due to having same **dataSource array** for the sections, in your case `postsArray` , when you append the item to `postsArray` on clicking the button , same `postsArray` is used for other sections, so after you insert the row in `section 0` , `section 1` complains that number of rows for me before and after insert operation is not same, but `section 0` doesnt complain because it has same number of rows and number of items in `postsArray`

Now this problem can be solved in two ways:

First way is that you can insert the row for other sections as well, then all the sections have equal number of rows as the number of elements in `postsArray`

Second way is that you have different dataSource arrays for all the sections , like `postsArray1` for section 1, `postsArray2` for section 2 and same for other sections.  Now in this case you dont need to insert rows for other sections , since each section has different dataSource array, changing one wont affect others.

I have made a simple project to demonstrate the above theory:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)))
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        }


        var valuesFirstSection = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
        var valuesSecondSection = ["value1Second", "value2Second", "value3Second"]

        //if you want to have the same dataSource array then use this

        //var sharedValues = ["value1Shared", "value2Shared", "value3Shared"] // shared dataSource array


        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                return 2
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

                if section == 0 {
                        return valuesFirstSection.count
                }else {
                        return valuesSecondSection.count
                }
//              //if you want to have the same dataSource array then
                //use this

                //return sharedValues.count;
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

                if indexPath.section == 0 {
                        cell.textLabel?.text = valuesFirstSection[indexPath.row]


                }else {

                        cell.textLabel?.text = valuesSecondSection[indexPath.row]

                }
                return cell

                //if you want to have the same dataSource array then
                //use this

                //cell.textLabel?.text = sharedValues[indexPath.row]
                //return cell

        }

        func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {



                //if you want to have the same dataSource array then
                //you need to insert the rows for other sections as well
//                sharedValues.insert("NewValue0", at: 0)
//                self.tableView.insertRows(
//                        at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0),
//                             IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
//                        ],
//                        with: .automatic)


                valuesFirstSection.insert("NewValue0", at: 0)
                self.tableView.insertRows(
                        at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                        ],
                        with: .automatic)


        }



}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, that worked. The issue with this now in my App is that I am won't be able to pre-define arrays for all of the sections because the amount of sections depends on the user. Is there a way to have it still work even if I don't know the amount of sections?

Comment: @Mr.Man "the amount of sections depends on the user" , please explain more

Comment: This tableview is supposed to be for users to see other peoples posts. For example, if User1 may only have 1 section if they do not follow a lot of people. Where User2 may have 50 sections if they do follow a lot of people.

Comment: @Mr.Man it depends on how you are getting the data for users, lets say you get two arrays of posts for user1 it means user1 will have 2 sections, right? Since this is different from your original problem ,you should ask a new question and give related info so others can help you also

Comment: Ok, so lets say I make a GET call to my backend, which will return the number of posts for the user. Let's say this number is 5. How will I be able to create 5 new arrays to put inside `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: @Mr.Man I think you can make an array of arrays , and in `numberOfRowsInSection` method you can access the array for section as the index of the outside array e.g `let aCount = 6

var arrSection = [[Int?]]()

for i in 0..<aCount {
        arrSection.append([])
}

print(arrSection)

arrSection[0].append(10)
print(arrSection)`